# How do I sign a message with my keypair

Tags: keypair

I want to prove i'm the owner of a certain wallet. (Assuming) I am technically inept - what is the easiest way to sign a custom message with my keypair and pass a public key to a recipient for verification.

Comment: I realize the easiest way to prove ownership is to send a transaction from that wallet, but was curious if there was an offline way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sign a message a message using Javscript with the following:

```
import { Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";
import nacl from "tweetnacl";
import { decodeUTF8 } from "tweetnacl-util";

(async () => {
  const keypair = Keypair.generate();

  const message = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
  const messageBytes = decodeUTF8(message);

  const signature = nacl.sign.detached(messageBytes, keypair.secretKey);
  const result = nacl.sign.detached.verify(
    messageBytes,
    signature,
    keypair.publicKey.toBytes()
  );

  console.log(result);
})();
```

Here we use `nacl` from `tweetnacl-util` to sign using the keypair's secret key. The message can then be verified using `nacl.sign.detached.verify`.

Other examples can be found on the [SolanaCookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html#how-to-sign-and-verify-messages-with-wallets).